# How to let a div open when a link inside is clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I need to know how to let a div stay open when clicking a link inside it.

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4hpgb/)

Please check the example above. A `<div>` contains an `a/link`.  When the `<div>` is clicked, its class is toggled.  I'd like to prevent the class from being toggled when the `a/link` is clicked.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="out">
    <div class="content">
        <a>click here to learn more..</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="side">
</div>
```

and here is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#out").click(function(event) {
        if (!$(event.target).is('a')){
            $(this).toggleClass("side");
        }
    });
    $(".side").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("out");
    });
});
```

Comment: Add code here. Because if jsFiddle will gone you question will not say anything for others.

Comment: btw, there is a search box on this site. You should try to use it

Comment: Sorry i'm kind of new to stackoverflow, i will provide code next time. Thanks for mentioning! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#out").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("side");
    });
    $(".side").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("out");
    });
    $('.content a').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();})
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4hpgb/1/)**

Comment: lol, i've seen stoppropagation before, tried it in the code also, but never worked. Now i know what the problem was.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make the `toggleClass` change conditional upon what was clicked. If you collect the `event` object as an argument, you can check to see if it's target was a link, and only toggle the class if the target is not a link.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#out").click(function(event) {
        if (!$(event.target).is('a')){
            $(this).toggleClass("side");
        }
    });
    $(".side").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("out");
    });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4hpgb/2/

Comment: this is also a nice variation for this code. this works fine too Thanks!